# How to create a new tab that is created and controlled by extension in developer console of chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to build an extension like React dev tools or Vue dev tools. So I need the extension to have a dedicated tab in the developer console of the browser.

I am hoping I will create custom HTML, CSS and JS to console the section of the chrome developer tab.

But I am not able to find this documentation or property which controls this. can anyone guide me on how I can achieve the same? Eg in the below image react devtools extensions creates a new Components Tab that it controls. I want to build a similar interaction.

[image]

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools